# svn property mergeinfo missing

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, collabnet

I have a project with 2 branches let's say v1.1 en v1.2 (in the same svn repository).
In v1.1 I modified 2 files and comitted them seperatly (2 revisions).
Now I wanted to merge revision 1 into v1.2 and block revision 2 (may not merged).

(I use eclipse 64-bit with subclipse a Collabnet for merging.)

For the first I choose 'merge a range of revisions', pick revision 1 and merge this into v1.2 and commit.

For the second I choose ... (block one or more revisions); I select revision 2. First symptom of the problem is noticeable here: the already merged revision is still in the list. Anyway, I follow the *'ignore what I don't understand'* procedure and continue. A few steps later eclipse asks me if I want to commit the updated mergeinfo property? I choose Yes. Next I get the message *'No files were changed or added since last commit'*.

When I restart a merge and choose 'select range of revisions' then I still see both in the list: the already merge revision A and the blocked revision B. When I look at the properties of the project I don't see a single property called svn:mergeinfo. I'm new to this but I thought that was the way svn stores this information?

thanks,
Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade your repo to 1.6.x before this will work.

Comment: thanks, I thought the server was on 1.4 (it's one I 'rent') but after a closer look it was still 1.4. Fortunately I did have the option to upgrade it to 1.5 and fortunately 1.5 also supports it. Problem solved!